# Custom USB device driver, Windows

Tags: windows, usb, driver

I don't have any experience writing drivers, but have a decent grasp on architecture, and programming languages. I wanted to create a custom driver (for fun / educational experience) for the rock band drum set.

This may be a little bit ambitious, but I'm just looking for a place to  start. Need to find some resources.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What platform do you want to write for

Comment: I'd imagine that you don't actually need a custom driver as the existing HID class driver already works. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say [WDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428) from microsoft is the place to start.